# Download file from servlet

Tags: java, javascript, jsp

In my servlet, I have a path where a file logs.txt exists like below,

```
String loc = "/u/xyz/workspace/FirstServlet/WebContent/WEB-INF/logs.txt";
```

and added the following line to my servlet and redirected response to jsp page,

```
String result = "<a href='"+loc+"' target='_blank'>Download result</a>";
```

Everything works fine but when I click the Download Result it returns a resource not found exception, I want to download logs.txt file to my client downloads folder.

What is my mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this by passing `path` from servlet to Java script by using `request.setAttribute(arg0, arg1)`

```
<script type='text/javascript'> 
function saveTextAsFile()
{

   var textToWrite = "SOME TEXT YOU WANT TO WRITE"
   var textFileAsBlob = new Blob([textToWrite], {type:'.txt'});
   var fileNameToSaveAs = "my.txt";

  var downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
  downloadLink.download = fileNameToSaveAs;
   if (window.webkitURL != null)
   {
     downloadLink.href = window.webkitURL.createObjectURL(textFileAsBlob);
   }
   else
   {
     downloadLink.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(textFileAsBlob);
     downloadLink.style.display = "none";
     document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
  }

 }
</script>
```

[Check this for downloading file from servlet](http://www.mkyong.com/servlet/servlet-code-to-download-text-file-from-website-java/)