# Download a file from servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I am trying to download a file to the client machine, the file exists in my servlet WEB-INF folder

So, in my doGet() I have something like this,

```
String path = "/u/my/workspace/FirstServlet/WebContent/WEB-INF/04:04:2014/logs.txt";
String result = "<a href='"+path+"' target='_blank'>Download result</a>";
request.setAttribute("ViewResult", result);
```

in my jsp I have,

```
<div>${ViewResult}</div>
```

but this is not downloading the file but is returning a `HTTP 404 requested resource not found` even though the file is there.

So based [on this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3502267/download-a-file-using-ajax) I've tried

```
response.setHeader("Content-Type", "text");
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename="+path);
```

though it has downloaded a file, the contents of the file are same as my jsp page source code.

How to do this right?

Comment: Everything within `WEB-INF` is not accessible externally. A path on your server is not a link to a webpage.

Comment: Okay so how do I do this? what should be the work around?

Comment: you could do something more along the lines of this:

http://balusc.blogspot.ca/2007/07/fileservlet.html

Comment: you write to the response's output stream. You can do a search in that last page for 'response.getOutputStream()' you will see a try/finally where the bytes from the file are written to the response's output stream

Comment: @Code you're on the right track with the code you already have using the response.setHeader methods. Keep going. you can do it

Comment: possible duplicate of [Download file from servlet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22852288/download-file-from-servlet)